# Nuxt Content - Named Slot Does Not Display

Tags: vue.js, markdown, nuxt.js

I am trying to used named slots in the Test Component as shown [in the docs](https://content.nuxtjs.org/writing#vue-components) but nothing is showing up, am I missing something or is this a bug? When I use props in the Topic Component it displays as expected.

***Edit***

farincz's question made me realize that the tags (div, h2, etc) were showing up but there is no content in any of them so nothing is showing up on the page. So if I inspect I see the tags but all the data that should be passed into the named-slot disappears.

Test Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>
                <slot name="testheader"></slot>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <slot name="testcontent"></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Topic Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>{{header}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>{{content}}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["header", "content"]
    };
</script>
```

test.md:

```
//This shows
    <topic name="introduction" id="introduction" header="Typography Introduction2" content="Blue bottle crucifix vinyl post-ironic four dollar toast vegan taxidermy.">
    </topic>
        
//This does not
    <test>
        <template #testheader>Introduction</template>
        <template #testcontent>Blue bottle crucifix vinyl post-ironic four dollar toast vegan taxidermy. Gastropub indxgo juice poutine</template>
    </test>
```

***Additional Info***
There are no errors in console and I imported the components as usual on the page that holds `<nuxt-content :document="doc" />`:

```
import Topic from "@/components/Topic";
import Test from "@/components/Test";

...

components: {
            Topic,
            Test
        },
```

Comment: how did you register the components? do you get a warning of an unknown custom tag in the console?

Comment: Updated with snippet. I imported them as usual on the page holding the `<nuxt-content>` tag and there are no errors.

Comment: Did rest of component markup generate? like H2 tag. In other words, is component correctly generate except slots or is something wrong with whole component?

Comment: If you are on vue < 2.6.0 you have to use the normal not shortend way of defining slottemplates `<template v-slot:testheader>...`. Just a guess...

Comment: The tags showed up but they were all empty.